# Enabling TLS in Windows CE 5.0

Tags: ssl, windows-ce

We are having a difficult time using TLS in our Windows CE 5.0 device.  What we have is a secure web server running on the device; currently it is using SSL 3.0 as the security provider, but we would like connections to use TLS instead.  Per the MSDN documentation, we have changed the registry settings under HKLM/Comm/SecurityProviders/Schannel/Protocols.  We've changed the "Enabled" value under SSL 3.0/Client and SSL 3.0/Server from 1 to 0 (SSL 2.0 and PCT 1.0 are also disabled) and verified that TLS 1.0/Client/Enabled and TLS 1.0/Server/Enabled are both set to 1.

After saving the registry and rebooting the device, we are unable to connect using IE, Firefox, or Chrome.  Using Wireshark, we've verified that the device sees the incoming request, but it simply refuses it.

We've made these same changes on Windows CE 6.0 and they work as expected.

Has anyone had any similar issues?  Does anyone know of any fix or workaround (we've got all QFEs for CE 5.0 as part of our image).